# Build in display doesn't show a screen

Tags: boot, 16.04, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I'm using UX21A Asus Zenbook Prime.

When I connected HDMI socket to an external display and turn on the laptop, Ubuntu didn't show build in display even it said display was recognized and activated. It happened on Ubuntu 16.04 and Linux Mint 18 Mint even when they were started as Live USB booting.

When I switched off the build in display and reactivate it through Display Setting GUI, it started showing. But with `xrandr` command, it didn't.

I unplugged HDMI and turn on the laptop and plug HDMI again after confirmed the BIOS Logo, the problem didn't show up.

The situation I confirmed on several environment were all the same.

It suppose to be caused by a problem which the laptop considers the external display as primary one.

So currently, I unplug the HDMI when I start it up.

Is there any good solutions?

Comment: Here will be the same problem.

Comment: https://forums.ubuntulinux.jp/viewtopic.php?id=6902

Comment: This topic moved to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1631678